# Height button in e-mails

Tags: html, css, email

I have a problem with height button in e-mail.

When I open the html file email in a browser button it is displayed correctly.

[html in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV3WQ.png)

However, when it comes to e-mail the customer is too narrow.

[html in e-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B31g1.png)

My code

```html
<tr>
<td align="center">
<a href="{guest_tracking_url}?id_order={order_name}" style="background-color: #ee1000; color:#ffffff; display:block; width:220px; font-size:14px; line-height:40px; text-decoration:none; margin-top:20px;" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=sk&amp;q={guest_tracking_url}?id_order={order_name}">Zistiť aktuálny stav objednávky
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding` instead of `width`

```
padding: 10px 20px; /* something like that */
```

**UPDATE:**

That's from an email I got this morning:

[image]

```
color: #fff!important;
text-decoration: none;
border: 0;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #651a84;
line-height: 1em;
padding: 18px 30px;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Thank You my firend.
Please tell me how to set margin top and bottom for this button. Text around too close button.

Comment: @BranislavHáz if `margin: <top>px 0 <bottom>px 0` on the button don't work for you, you can use a container `<div>` with padding as a workaround.

Comment: Hi @BranislavHáz if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding, like that:

```
padding: 20px 30px;
```

And your text will be vertically centered in the button.

Answer (score 0):

The browser may have some default padding, which the rendering engine of your email client doesn't have. So simpy set it manually uing `padding`.

In your case, you may want to specify the padding for top/bottom and left/right like this: `padding: 5px 10px` This would result in 5px top/bottom and 10px right-left: Feel free to define an invidivual padding to every side, which may not make much sense here, but is also possible if required by passing it clockwise like `padding: 1px 2px 3px 4px` (result: 1px top, 2px right, 3px bottom, 4px left)

Comment: Thank You my firend. Please tell me how to set margin top and bottom for this button. Text around too close button.

Comment: @BranislavHáz You can use my example and set margins/paddings you don't want to set (e.g. right) to zero or any value you want. Alternatively, if you want to set certain paddings, use a prefix for their direction. Example: `padding-top: 10px` will set only the top padding to 10 px and leave others untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line height and add the padding

```
padding: 10px 15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for tips.

But when I add padding to button, text around too close button :/

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5MNI.png)

Comment: Use margins like `margin-bottom: 10px`. And you should edit the question instead of writing an anwesear, since your post doesn't answear your questions.